# How to read PLIST in a structure manner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This how i construct my PLIST.

```
<dict>
<key>level1</key>
<dict>
<key>formation</key>
<dict>
    <key>height</key>
    <integer>34</integer>
    <key>width</key>
    <integer>12</integer>

</dict>
</dict>
</dict>
```

level>formation>data

This is the example code i used, but it didnt work.

```
//init loading from PLIST here, and then associate value.
NSString *pathString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Levels",targetWorld];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathString ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *levelNameNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:targetLevel];

NSDictionary *levelsList = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *level = [levelsList objectForKey:levelNameNumber];

NSEnumerator *levelFormations = [level objectEnumerator];

for( NSDictionary *worldSize in levelFormations )
{
    worldWidth = [[worldSize objectForKey:@"width"] intValue];
    worldHeight = [[worldSize objectForKey:@"height"] intValue];

    NSLog(@"height is %d",worldHeight);
    NSLog(@"width is %d",worldWidth);

}

[levelNameNumber release];
[levelsList release];
```

problem with this code is that it runs a second for loop and returns both the height and width to ZERO.

Any idea? or how do i do it the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an object from levelsList, and you're releasing levelsList at the end, the level object you got from the dictionary will also be released. You either need to not release levelsList, retain level, or preferably start using ARC.

Comment: I tried to do it without releasing and it didn't work. I've changed to a different code structure, without using fast enumeration. Now it works. thanks for the suggestion on ARC tho

Answer (score 0):

Check your plist with plutil and ensure it has a valid syntax.

More details here: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/can_i_check_my_plist_files_in_mac_os_x_for_problems.html

Comment: The plist doesn't seems to have any problem. that for loop above does get me the correct value, however it runs a second loop after the first which gave me the correct value and return it back to 0.

Comment: In that case I would look at your retain-release pattern. Since you release levelsList at the end, you can't use it later unless you reallocate it, as LearnCocos2D said below.